# Creating a random password generates a password with length 0: Blame JavaScript or Java Servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, passwords

When my users forget their passwords, they are sent to the page shown below. I generate a random password in JavaScript, encrypt it, and send both the plain text and md5 hash to a Servlet. The Servlet then e-mails the password to the user and stores the md5 hash in my  database. This process works fine most of the time. But for some reason frequently generates an error where the generated password has length 0.

I tested my JavaScript code separately and had it generate hundreds of passwords. None had length 0. So where is this error coming from?

Here is the HTML form:

```
//This method returns a randomly generated mathy password.
function randomPassword(theForm) {
  first = ["Euler", "Erdos", "Newton", "Eucl1d", "Gauss", "H1lb3rt", "Cantor",    "Bernoulli", "PascaL"];
  second = ["Const", "Number", "Theorem", "Prime", "Ratio", "Lemma", "Postulate", "Method", "Algorithm"];
  symbol = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","_","+","-","?"];
  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * second.length);
  n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  style = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);  //0,1, or 2
  if(style==0)   password = first[a] + n + second[b];
  else if(style==1)  password = first[a] + second[b] + n;
  else password = first[a] + second[b] + symbol[n];
  theForm['newPass'].value = password;
  theForm['passwordLog'].value = "style="+style + "  a=" + a + ", b=" + b+ ", n=" + n;
  hashField = theForm['passHash'];
  hashField.value = hex_md5(password);
  theForm.submit();
```

}

```
<body>
    <h2>You can reset your password below.</h2>
    <form action="ResetPassword" method="post" > 
        Enter your e-mail address:
        <input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail" size="20"/> <br />
        <input type="button" value="Reset Password" onclick="randomPassword(this.form);" />
        <input type="hidden" id="passHash" name="passHash" /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="newPass" name="newPass" /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="passwordLog" name="passwordLog" /> 
    </form><br/>
    <strong>Attention Coaches: If you are having trouble logging into this system,
please contact the scorekeeper: llaspina@bethpage.ws </strong>
</body>
```

And here is the Servlet that receives the form data sent from the above file:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ResetPasswordServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ResetPassword"})
public class ResetPasswordServlet extends HttpServlet {  
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    java.sql.Connection con = pool.getConnection();
    String emailAddress = request.getParameter("eMail");
    String newPass = request.getParameter("newPass");
    String passHash = request.getParameter("passHash");
    String log = request.getParameter("passwordLog");
    try {
        Coach coach = null;
        ArrayList<Coach> coachList = MathTeamDAO.getAllCoaches(con);
        for(Coach c : coachList) {
            if(c.email.equals(emailAddress) ) {
                coach = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        out.println("<html><head><title>Scorekeeper Reset Password Servlet</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Reset Password Servlet</h1>");
        if(coach==null) {
            out.println("Your email address was not found in our database.<br/>" +
            "Please contact the scorekeeper or the secretary to gain access to the sytem.");
        }
        else {
            if(newPass == null || newPass.length()<3) {
                out.print("An error occurred while generating a random password.  The randomly generated password came back as ");
                out.print(newPass);
                out.println(" Please try to <a href=\"resetPassword.html\">reset your password</a> again.");
                String errorMsg = "An error was encountered while attempting a password reset. ";
                if(newPass==null)
                    errorMsg += "null newPass generated.";
                else
                    errorMsg += " The newPass had length " + newPass.length() + " and =" + newPass;
                if(log!=null)
                    errorMsg += ("\n" + log);
                if(UtilityServlet.emailAnError(coach,errorMsg, this.getServletName() + " at " + this.getServletName()))
                    out.println("<br/>The scorekeeper was just informed of this error through email, so you do not need to report it.");
            }
            else {
                out.println("<h3>Check your email for your new password and directions for signing into the scorekeeper system.</h3>");
                out.print("Sending new password to " + coach.email + "<br/>");
                ChangePasswordServlet.changePassword(con, coach.schoolID, passHash);
                School herSchool = MathTeamDAO.getSchoolByCoach(con, coach);
                String emailServerMessage = ChangePasswordServlet.sendPasswordEmail(coach, herSchool.shortName, newPass);
                if(herSchool!=null) {
                    out.print("<br/>The username for " + herSchool.fullName);
                    out.print(" is <strong>");
                    out.print(herSchool.username);
                    out.println("</strong><br/>");
                }
                out.print(emailServerMessage);
            }
            out.flush();
        }
        out.println("<br/>Return to <a href=\"login.jsp\" >login page.</a>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    } 
    catch(java.sql.SQLException utoh) {   }
    finally { 
        pool.freeConnection(con);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Notice that I am having error messages sent to myself if the password is null or too short. This happens fairly regularly and they always have length 0. Why?

Comment: "I generate a random password in JavaScript, encrypt it, and send both the plain text and md5 hash to a Servlet" - this sounds horrifyingly insecure (what's your encryption?), and if your actual algorithm is anything close to your code sample, you're generating scarily insecure passwords. (<10 bits entropy, and you're disclosing your entire generation method to attackers so you don't even have the marginal benefit of obscurity.)

Comment: I know this doesn't help solve your question - but is there a reason you generate the password client-side, then send it to the server?  Seems unnecessarily complex and potentially insecure, compared to simply advising the server that a user needs their password reset, and having it generate the password.  (ie., a hacker could use your client-side encryption to reset anyone's password to something of their own choosing).

Answer (score 1):

With the comment in the middle of this line:

```
else //if(style==2)  password = first[a] + second[b] + symbol[n];
```

you are going to get undefined passwords in about a third of the cases...

Comment: If that comments exists in the code then it will always become undefined since the last else is matched with the `theForm['newPass'].value = password`. So the password is only set ***when*** the style is 2, but it is set to undefined. All other cases it is empty string since the password field is left unaltered..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Since the OP's not declaring `password` with `var`, could the password be set to some random unrelated global variable of that name in the "correct" cases?

Comment: Sorry for that code typo. I was trying to condense the code a bit and in reformatting it I commented out the else clause. When the JavaScript code was tested, it never generated a 0 length password.

Answer (score 1):

```
else //if(style==2)  password = first[a] + second[b] + symbol[n];
theForm['newPass'].value = password;
```

With the comment there, the `else` is now affecting `theForm['newPass'].value = password;`, meaning the value will not be set, causing an empty password.

This is why using `{}` is recommended even if you only have one statement.

Comment: Sure, but that was just a typo (see updated code now ) when I pasted the code into my browser and tried to condense it a bit. If this was the problem then I would have seen it when testing the JavaScript directly. Other ideas?